# php and jquery image selector

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I was on flickr and I saw this function whereby you can scroll photos (thumbnail) without loading the page. It's probably using jQuery or json but does anyone know whats the proper name for this kind of function or is there any available libraries?
 I've uploaded a screenshot..

[image: flickr snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Use this JQuery plug in .. its great [Image slider](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/autoscroll.html)

and easy to integrate.

Comment: hi same Q as above. am i allow to trigger something when i select a photo?? is it built in with the libraries?

Comment: ahh stupid me.. okay i read the specifications and yes it does =)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Carousel plugin... There's lots of them

I like this one: [Cloud Carousel](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm)

And this: [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: hi, this libs looks good. but am i allow to trigger something when i select a photo?? is it built in with the libraries?

Comment: Yes, in fact, they do not change the markup too much. In jCarousel, each item is a li. Just bind any event to it, exactly as you already do with jQuery, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is just simple ul li combination and the images

Comment: he need some help to make slider like gallery.

Comment: @Ummar , image like sliders are available on internet FREE we just need to download that and need to make necessary changes (like height,width)...

Comment: @Ummar , he is asking 4 image slider

Answer (score 0):

You could either use pre-built libraries like the ones mentioned in other answers, or build from scratch.

Generally, these kind of widgets use an AJAX approach, where images are loaded separately from the page, and the animation stuff is achieved using a mixture of JS and CSS.